# Tracing errors in sklearn tests

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When running `nosetests sklearn --exe` with the latest version of `sklearn`, I run into three errors, and I can't figure out where they come from:

```
$ nosetests sklearn --exe
.............................................................../home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/spect
ral_embedding.py:225: UserWarning: Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding may not works as expected.                                             
  warnings.warn("Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding"
...........SS...............S.....................................................S.........................................................S...............
..........................SSSF...................../home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/test/test
_func_inspect.py:122: UserWarning: Cannot inspect object <functools.partial object at 0x130fd7e0>, ignore list will not work.                              
  nose.tools.assert_equal(filter_args(ff, ['y'], (1, )),
............................................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................................
............S...............................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................................
............................................................................................................................................................
.................................................................................................SSS....S....S..............................................
.....................................E...............................................                                                                      
======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_pls.test_scale
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/tests/test_pls.py", line 235, in test_scale
    clf.fit(X, Y)
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pls.py", line 320, in fit
    linalg.inv(np.dot(self.x_loadings_.T, self.x_weights_)))
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/scipy/scipy-0.12.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 380, in inv
    raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
LinAlgError: singular matrix

======================================================================
FAIL: sklearn.externals.joblib.test.test_disk.test_disk_used
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/jacob04/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/test/test_disk.py", line 41, in test_disk_used
    nose.tools.assert_true(disk_used(cachedir) < target_size + 12)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1603 tests in 102.191s

FAILED (SKIP=14, errors=1, failures=1)
```

Here is the result of `pip freeze`:

$ pip freeze

```
Cython==0.19.1
PIL==1.1.7
PyXB==1.2.2
PyYAML==3.10
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.34
epc==0.0.5
ipython==0.13.2
jedi==0.6.0
matplotlib==1.3.x
nltk==2.0.4
nose==1.3.0
numexpr==2.1
numpy==1.7.1
pandas==0.11.0
pyparsing==1.5.7
python-dateutil==2.1
pytz==2013b
rpy2==2.3.1
scikit-learn==0.13.1
scipy==0.12.0
sexpdata==0.0.3
six==1.3.0
stemming==1.0.1
-e git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables.git@df7b20444b0737cf34686b5d88b4e674ec85575b#egg=tables-dev
tornado==3.0.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

This is all with `Python 2.7.4`. Why am I getting these errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: As I said on the ML, you should upgrade to 0.13.1 to get rid of the errors and also to get the other bugfixes.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasMueller Updating to 0.13.1 got rid of some errors, but some stayed. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: which stayed? There could be some concerning SVC or possibly LocallyLinearEmbedding possibly...

Comment: Thanks @AndreasMueller I updated the OP with the new log.

Answer (score 0):

Please report the PLS error in the issue tracker. Not sure where the joblib error comes from. You shouldn't worry about the error too much, though.